Vite not including all assets after build
So, whenever I build my application using vite, and I am using SolidJS some of my svgs that I am importing isn't included in the final build folder.
This is how I am importing the svgs (inline tsx file)
import Head from "../assets/svgs/head.svg";
import Body from "../assets/svgs/body.svg";
import LeftArm from "../assets/svgs/leftArm.svg";
import RightArm from "../assets/svgs/rightArm.svg";
import LeftLeg from "../assets/svgs/leftLeg.svg";
import RightLeg from "../assets/svgs/rightLeg.svg";

Then I use the svgs like so:
const bodyParts = [{
    name: "Head",
    id: "head",
    image: Head
}, {
    name: "Body",
    id: "body",
    image: Body
}, {
    name: "Left Arm",
    id: "leftArm",
    image: LeftArm
}, {
    name: "Right Arm",
    id: "rightArm",
    image: RightArm
}, {
    name: "Left Leg",
    id: "leftLeg",
    image: LeftLeg
}, {
    name: "Right Leg",
    id: "rightLeg",
    image: RightLeg
}];

And then I iterate over that inside of the render part, and then set it as background-image:
<div
    class={styles.image}
    style={{
        "background-image": `url("${bodyPart.image}")`
    }}
/>

I tried following the vite documentation about how to import inline svgs, but everything they said to try didn't work.

You are mixing inlining of SVG with SVG as img, you should use one or the other.
Providing correct image path should solve your problem:
<div
    class={styles.image}
    style={{
        "background-image": `url("/assets/svgs/rightLeg.svg")`
    }}
/>


There is nothing wrong with your approach. There is probably a big somewhere else but it could be a number of things. Maybe the images just have zero size. Try inspecting the source, or:
        <div
            style={{
                "background-image": `url("${item.image}")`,
                "width": "100px",
                "height": "100px",
            }}
        />

